# I/O buffer cache for disk file in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a question about kernel I/O cache for disk file.
As I know when write() or read() is called, there's a buffer cache in kernel space for disk file I/O operation.
My question is that, is this I/O buffering only applies to disk file, or it also applies to terminal, FIFO, pipe, and sockets?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called the "page cache".  It consists of pages backed by files and "anonymous pages" backed by swap.  This is all part of the Linux virtual memory (VM) subsystem.

It is not used for TTYs, FIFOs, pipes, or sockets.  Each of those do provide buffering of their own by their nature; for example, the data you write to a pipe has to reside somewhere before it is read back out again.  But that buffering has nothing to do with the VM subsystem.

[update]

Note that this buffering is totally independent of the user-space buffering provided by (e.g.) `fwrite()`.  (I see you asked a similar question earlier, and it is not clear whether you understand the distinction.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nemo.
As I understand, "normally" read()/write() to disk file won't block because of this page cache.
So is it because of the different buffering mechanism that makes read/write to pipe, fifo, socket, tty may block?

Comment: Yeah, I know the difference of them~~

Comment: `read` can always block if the data is not available; that includes reading a file whose contents are not already in the page cache.  `write` to a file _may_ block if there are too many dirty pages (as determined by `vm.dirty_ratio`).  Writing to a pipe will not block unless the pipe buffer is full.  Similarly, writing to a socket will not block unless the socket buffer is full.  Maybe you should ask a question that says what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I am not clear about when and how these blocking read/write happens for various kind of files.
Thanks, Nemo, I will ask another question for this.